# Chiral spin liquid flux states on the Kagome lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, chirality, spin-models

Short version: 
Is it possible to arrange the fluxes for the Kagomé lattice with triangle flux $\phi_\triangle=\frac{\pi}2$ and hexagon flux $\phi_{hex}=0$ **using a single unit cell**?

Longer version:
I am looking at fermionic mean field theories on the Kagomé lattice that describe a chiral spin liquid state for spin-1/2. Skipping the derivation (in [1](http://scitation.aip.org/docserver/fulltext/aip/journal/jap/69/8/1.347830.pdf?expires=1467232497&id=id&accname=2105756&checksum=19B8D53FE3EF7951F52949898C6D2B3F) and [2](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.117205)), the mean field Hamiltonian is

$H = -\sum\limits_{\langle i, j\rangle,\sigma}~\rho~e^{iA_{ij}}~f^\dagger_{i\sigma}~f_{j\sigma} + H.c.$

This basically says that $f$-fermions hop along nearest-neighbor links, picking up a phase $A_{ij}$ one way along the bond, and $-A_{ij}$ hopping in the reverse direction. Phases (aka gauge field) are assigned to each lattice link in a unit cell, often depicted with arrows. The flux $\phi$ is defined as the sum of phases on a closed lattice plaquette along, say, the counter-clockwise direction.

In [Marston's paper (Ref. 1)](http://scitation.aip.org/docserver/fulltext/aip/journal/jap/69/8/1.347830.pdf?expires=1467232497&id=id&accname=2105756&checksum=19B8D53FE3EF7951F52949898C6D2B3F), and [Ran's paper (Ref. 2)](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.117205), they introduce a state with triangle flux $\frac{\pi}2$ and hexagon flux 0 (equivalent to [Chua's (Ref. 5) (d)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp8Vr.png)), and SL-[$\frac{\pi}2$,0] in [Kim's diagram (Ref. 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pbM1.png).

[image: Flux assignments From Ref. 5]

[image: Phase and Flux assignments From Ref. 6, referencing Ref. 2]

My problem is with that with [Kim's (Ref. 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pbM1.png) phase assignment for the triangles, I don't see how it is possible to achieve zero (or 2$\pi$) hexagon flux, unless one uses a doubled magnetic unit cell, as is claimed in [Chua's work (Ref. 5)](http://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.83.180412). [Ran (Ref. 2)](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.117205) doesn't explicitly state whether the unit cell has to double or not. Am I missing something here?

[J. B. Marston and C. Zeng, J. Appl. Phys. 69, 8 (1991), Spin‐Peierls and spin‐liquid phases of Kagomé quantum antiferromagnets](http://scitation.aip.org/docserver/fulltext/aip/journal/jap/69/8/1.347830.pdf?expires=1467232497&id=id&accname=2105756&checksum=19B8D53FE3EF7951F52949898C6D2B3F)

[Y. Ran, M. Hermele, P. A. Lee, and X.-G. Wen, PRL 98, 117205 (2007), Projected-Wave-Function Study of the Spin-1/2 Heisenberg Model on the Kagome ́Lattice](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.117205)

[V. Chua, H. Yao and G. A. Fiete, PRB 83, 180412(R) (2011), Exact chiral spin liquid with stable spin Fermi surface on the kagome lattice](http://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.83.180412)

[Jung Hoon Kim & Jung Hoon Han talk, http://manybody.skku.edu/manybody/ppt/Chiral_Spin_States_Pyrochlore-A3-Shanghai.pdf](http://manybody.skku.edu/manybody/ppt/Chiral_Spin_States_Pyrochlore-A3-Shanghai.pdf)